# TableView populated by xml needs to section data and create A-Z index on right of table

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

Basically my tableview is populated with a list of street names which is data parsed from an XML that has the streets Alphabetically sorted.

The XML has several streets for A, B, C and so on. (more than 1 basically and different sizes for each)

The problem is: Basically it adds the whole array to Section A,  Section B and so on.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    return [self.filteredListContent count];
}
else
{
    return [xmlDataArray count];
}  
}
```

I need a way to break up the XML once parsed into multiple arrays to populate the streets that are contained in A, B, C, etc., into its correct section.

I have read multiple posts about creating a Dictionary and creating keys, but I have no idea how to do this from the parsed XML. Once I have it in the Dictionary, how can I populate the tableView? I have a separate array for the indexTitles, and the A-Z index is showing on the right. But of course this does not work as the data needs to be sorted into its own sections based on A-Z.

Any help or suggestions most appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of good tutorials for learning how to properly parse XML, here's a quickie:

in .h

```
@interface ObjectName : ObjectSuperclass <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSMutableString *currentElement;
    NSMutableString *childElement;
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
}

@end
```

in .m, insert these NSXMLParser Delegate Methods:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{    
  currentElement = nil;
  currentElement = [elementName copy];
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"xmlParentElement"]) {
    //This means the parser has entered the XML parent element named: xmlParentElement
    //All of the child elements that need to be stored in the dictionary should have their own IVARs and declarations.
    childElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
  //For all child elements, run this if statement.
  if (currentElement isEqualToString:@"childElement") {
    [childElement appendString:string];
  }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{   
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"parentElement"]) {
    [dictionary addObject:childElement forKey:@"childElement"];
    //And devise a system for indexing (this could be converting the address string in to an array and taking objectAtIndex:0.. any way you choose, add that object below:
    [dictionary addObject:@"A" forKey@"index"];
  }
}
```

Now that that's done, use the regular UITableViewController Delegate methods to create the table and in addition, use these delegate methods to create the side index:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return [dictionary objectForKey:@"index"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index{
  return index;
}
```

Comment: if things are unclear, I am more than happy to edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply early today I had the same idea you mentioned above after some head scratching. Sometimes you need a little more time to think these things over without getting frustrated. I will have a go and let you know how I get on. Thanks again.